# Upgrading to Rails 5 ActionView::Template::Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into String with image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, actionview

I'm upgrading from rails 4.2 to rails 5.1.1 and I have this strange breaking change in my email views.

I've enabled ApplicationMailer and made my WelcomeMailer inherit from it, but I haven't changed anything else and I'm getting this error in Sidekiq when I try to send any email.  This has always worked fine in Rails 4.  I've tried rewriting the url and removing the @ref.  Ref is not an object, it is a string calculated like

```
@ref = "#{variable_1}&#{variable_2}"
```

Here is the action view error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

It highlights both

```
= link_to email_links_url(link_label: 'root', ref: @ref ), target:"_blank"
  = image_tag "#{Rails.configuration.adjusted_image_path}branding/our-logo-mail.jpg", style: "width: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto", alt: "SomeCompany Name"
```

development.rb

```
config.adjusted_image_path = ""
```

Comment: Can you put the full error logs?

Comment: Q: why `@ref`? why not just `ref` ?